# match different regex from different log files and return the match only

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have different log files from which I am trying to match different error messages.

For an example I have taken only two log files, but I have more number of log files and from each log file, I need to match different `regex`, so I will be appending more and more `regex` with `|` in `re.findall`.

## my.log

```
UVM_ERROR: This is one error
UVM_ERROR: This is one error
This is my log file
```

## new.log

```
No such file or directory
This is a new log file
```

## temp.py

```
import sys
import re
f = open(sys.argv[1] , "r").read()
op = re.findall('(UVM_ERROR.*)|(No such file or directory)', f)[0]
print op
```

Output

```
$ python temp.py my.log
('UVM_ERROR: This is one error', '')

$ python temp.py new.log
('', 'No such file or directory')
```

Is there any way I can return only the matched value and not null like this?

```
$ python temp.py my.log
'UVM_ERROR: This is one error'

$ python temp.py new.log
'No such file or directory'
```

Do I need to make any changes in `re.findall` regex usage to get above output?

Comment: change to: `'(?:UVM_ERROR.*)|(?:No such file or directory)'` and then you will have only one group

Comment: You could also filter out the blank entries afterward.